# TeX programmer needed - or assistance with page dimensions and crop marks

Tags: tex-core, texlive, crop

is there a place where i can find/hire a TeX programmer to adjust TeX files that were set up for us in the 80s? I can make minor edits, but things like page dimensions and crop mark locations are beyond me. Our programmer is retired and we want to create a smaller version of our books. Unless of course someone can tell me an easy line of code to look for and change myself. thank you!

Comment: a list of consultants is included in the web pages of the tex users group: http://tug.org -- they list their areas of competence, so you should be able to find one there.

Comment: Or you can include the preamble in your question with one or two sample pages with dummy content and we can help you to set up a modernized workflow.

Comment: I am working for a company that does exactly this. If there is a way to contact you non-publicly, i can give you the name and a link to the company's website.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, by the way.